# Does "from module import *" affect the execution time of the program

Tags: python, import, module

Please tell me whether or not a `from module import *` statement affects the execution time of the program. The reason I am asking is because it imports all the functions available in the module.

Comment: There might be a negligible difference but nothing to worry about. There are better reasons not to use `import *`: https://pep8.org/#imports

Comment: Depends on what is inside the * :)

Comment: The difference between `import x` and `from x import *` is that the second one assigns names from `x` to variables in the namespace you're importing into. Both versions still execute the whole of module `x`. Any difference in execution time is negligible.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't save any time. I just tested it with the time module. Makes no difference whether you import the whole module or you import something from it. It is pretty convenient not having to write the module name for every function you want to use tho.

Answer (score -1):

Yes it does. Each function loaded into the interpreter needs resources. It is normally discouraged to use the `import *` when programming modules. It is also a little bit faster to directly call a function together with the module (e.g numpy.cos instead of importing cos). You could make just some tests with timeit or cProfile if you want to see for yourself.

Comment: "import module" statement also import all the functions from the module so they both are the same.

Comment: No they are not. By using `from module import smth` you load the function/oject smth directly into the namespace. When importing the module you don't load the content itself into the namespace. This was for example the reason `filter` was removed during the transition from python2 to python3 to slim the namespace.
Edit: Removed from the builtins namespace to be more specific.